# R: $ cannot be used for atomic vectors (box plot)

Tags: r, boxplot

[image]

I would love some advice on how to fix the error shown in the screenshot. I only started learning R yesterday so I'm not very familiar with it. I tried using % but this produced a different type of error (unexpected input). Are there any problems with how I've defined time_spen and species earlier on in the code?

Comment: `species` is a vector try `boxplot(species)`.

Comment: I guess you should try `boxplot(time_spen)`

Comment: Please don't add data or code as an image. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make a boxplot of the `time_spen` variable for each species? The `ggplot2` package can help.

Since I don't have your data, here is an example from the `penguins` dataset in the `palmerpenguins` package.

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(penguins) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = species, y = body_mass_g))
```

[image]